# Why doesn't my javascript work properly when I include Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Good afternoon,

I have been the whole afternoon trying to figure out a problem with my code. Interestingly enough, when I put my code on codepen it works just fine. On my computer, it does not. 
What happens is that I made a jquery code to add an effect of "fading in" to my elements when I scroll down the page. Then, in the middle of my work I decided that I wanted to use bootstrap and then I included it in the head section like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3-1.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">.
```

However, whenever I include the bootstrap file, my javascript fading function stops working properly. It's SO WEIRD. The weirdest part is that when I transfer over to codepen it works fine.

this is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         $('.hideme').each(function(i){
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            console.log($(this).position().top);


            // If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it 
            if(bottom_of_window > $(this).position().top){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);
             }


        }); 

    });



    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},'slow');
        return false;
    });

    $("#who").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".about").offset().top}, 'slow');
        return true;
        });

    $("#projects").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#projectsResponse").offset().top}, 'slow');
        return true;
        });

    $("#vision").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#qualities").offset().top}, 'slow');
        return true;
        });

    $("#contact").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#divisor_contato").offset().top}, 'slow');
        return true;
        });

    $("#contact2").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#divisor_contato").offset().top}, 'slow');
        return true;
        });


});
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: I imagine you are clashing with reserved words bootstrap is using. Try for example to add a '2' at the end of your classes and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading bootstrap after jquery at the end of your html page instead of the header right before the closing body tag. Maybe it's a loading sequence issue?